# How to change cell <td> color based on values in Data Table

Tags: datatable

I want to change the cell color based on a value in the data table. I've tried this code but its not working. Below are the sample code and the Data Table. Any idea & help is much appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var oTable = $('table').DaTable({ 
'rowCallback': function(row, data, index){
    if(data[6]=='Cleared')
    {
    $(row).find('td:eq(6)').css('color', 'green');
    }
    else
    {
      $(row).find('td:eq(6)'.css('color', 'red');
    }
  }
});
```

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed" 
   id="edp">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>EDP</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Course</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Dept.</th>
        <th>Clearance</th>
        <th>View</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php foreach($data as $display)
            {   
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "  
                <td>".$display->EDP."</td>
                <td>".$display->Lname.', '.$display->Fname.', '.$display->Mname."</td>
                <td>".$display->Course."</td>
                <td>".$display->Cyear."</td>
                <td>".$display->Dept."</td>
                <td>".$display->Status."</td>
                <td><a href='".base_url().'office/viewClearance/'.$display->EDP."'><img 
                class='viewicon' src='".base_url().'assets/icons/view.png'."'></td>
                </tr>";
            }
            ?>
    </tbody>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Live link  https://dotnetfiddle.net/rdL6IU

You can do this @*https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html*@

```
   $(function () {
        $('#example').dataTable({
            "createdRow": function (row, data, dataIndex) {
                if (data[0] == 'Garrett Winters') {
                    $(row).addClass('redClass');
                }
            }
        });
    })
```